# how can I position nested divs at the bottom and float right?

Tags: html, css

Say I have a parent div with three child divs.  Is there a way that I can position everything in the bottom right corner?  Something like this:

```
--------------------------------------
|                                    |
|                                    |
|                                    |
|                                    |
|                                    |
|                   test1 test2 test3|
|------------------------------------|
```

I tried this css:

```
   #header
    {
        position:relative;
    }
    #nav_tabs
    {
        position:relative;
        width:50%;
        height:100%;
        float:right;
    }
    .tab
    {
        position:absolute;
        bottom:0px;
        float:right;
    }
```

With this HTML:

```
<div id="header">
<div id="nav_tabs">
    <div class="tab">test1</div>
    <div class="tab">test2</div>
    <div class="tab">test3</div>
</div>
</div>
```

But it looks like it is stacking my tabs one on top of the other.  What is the correct way to do this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Do this.

```
#header
{
    width:500px;
    height:300px;
    position:relative;
    border:1px solid red;
}
#nav_tabs
{
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0;
    right:0;
}
.tab
{
    float:left;
    margin-right:5px;
}
```

### Check working example at http://jsfiddle.net/qpHNN/2/

Comment: What did you mean by width: 100?

Comment: It's a typo. I forgot it there while editing. Just remove it. I updated the answer.

Answer (score 2):

I played around with it and came up with something like this.

Please note, that this has some limitations, so if you need something different, you should define the requirements more clearly. The limitations are:

- the #header must have a specific or at least controlled height, because #nav_tabs is out of flow, so won't make it resize if needed.
- the solution is limited to 3 tabs, but of course the percentage can be changed

So here comes the CSS:

```
   #header
    {
        position:relative;
        height: 200px;
    }
    #nav_tabs
    {
        width:50%;
        position: absolute;
        right: 0;
        bottom: 0;
        overflow: hidden;
    }
    .tab
    {
        float: left;
        width: 33%;
        text-align: right;
    }
```

[**And a Live Demo that you can play with**](http://jsfiddle.net/bazmegakapa/ePfAX/1)

Answer (score -1):

Try this css:

```
#header
{
  position:relative;
}
#nav_tabs
{
  position:relative;
  width:50%; /* remove if you want at bottom right of page */
  height:100%;
}
#tabs
{
  position:absolute;
  bottom:0px;
  right:0px;
}
.tab {
  float:right;
}
```

And wrap the tabs with another div:

```
<div id="header">
  <div id="nav_tabs">
    <div id="tabs">
      <div class="tab">test1</div>
      <div class="tab">test2</div>
      <div class="tab">test3</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: This one does not work. It puts them to the left of the middle of #header.

Comment: Ah sorry. You had the width of nav_tabs at 50% so it would align them to the bottom right of that div, which happens to be the middle of the page.

Comment: Ok let's say we remove `width: 50%`. Why do we need the extra div anymore?

Comment: Good point :) I was just focussing on getting three elements to align next to each other in the bottom right of another. Now I feel like I have sinned.

Comment: I am drunk 8 in the morning and don't feel like I have sinned. You shouldn't either, I'm not trying to bitch, just to discuss.

Comment: Haha. I'm merely hungover at 8am; a far less desirable state. I appreciate all the feedback!

Comment: Be always drunk... no hangovers for sure.

Answer (score -2):

Instead of using nested divs I'd use a list, like this:

```
<div id="header">
 <div id="nav_tabs">
  <ul>
    <li class="tab">test1</div>
    <li class="tab">test2</div>
    <li class="tab">test3</div>
  </ul>
 </div>
</div>
```

And in the CSS class `tab` I'd add the CSS property `display` with the value `inline`:

```
.tab ul
{
 position:absolute;
 bottom:0px;
 float:left;
 display: inline;
}
```

I hope this works for you.